# All files put into a folder "foo" by user "a" or "b" should belong to the "bar" group and only be visible by them

Tags: linux, command-line, chmod, rhel, chgrp

**Pre requisite steps:**

1. Create two new user accounts "a" and "b"

   ```
   # useradd a
   # useradd b
   ```
2. Create a group "bar". Create a directory "foo".

   ```
   # groupadd bar
   # mkdir /tmp/foo
   ```

**Task:**

All files put into the "foo" directory by users "a" or "b" should
belong to the "bar" group and be only visible by them.

Answer (score 0):

## chgrp bar /tmp/foo [changes the group ownership of foo to bar due to which everything added to foo will belong to bar]

You can also set ACL permissions as:

## setfacl -m u:a:rwx /tmp/foo